# Jetpack compose live preview

Tags: android, live-preview, android-jetpack-compose

I just started working on jetpack compose and downloaded sample of **Jetnews**.

When I opened **MainActivity** or **JetnewsApp.kt** I am unable to see preview of Composable function, I added **@Preview** annotation as well but unable to see live preview.

Can anyone please help me to find live preview.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Preview never show after add `@Preview` annotation in `JetnewsApp` class. In my case after adding `@Preview` i close project and then open project again it's working fine for me in Macbook pro.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Before that we have to add `@Preview` on `JetnewsApp` to get preview.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun JetnewsApp() { ... }
```

---

You just need to check the **"Show Decorations"** option to show real layout preview.

You can toggle both preview using same option.

Check the below image:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Also invalidate and restart Android Studio if it doesn't work at first. Remember this is still in development.

Comment: @prany Please let me know from where this window will be open?

Comment: this just decorates the preview, if the preview pane is not visible then you don't even have this button

Comment: he said "I added @Preview annotation as well"

Comment: First I just misunderstood the que content. As I am trying the same example and by adding `@Preview` on `JetnewsApp`, I can see the preview. https://imgur.com/lbXE8I5

Comment: @KhizarHayat Check Akshay's answer. You need to add `@Preview` annotation to see preview.

Comment: Thanks pRaNay acutally i already added preview annotation but it didn't work at that time I build app and ropened class then this preview window automatically appeared.

Answer (score 2):

In **JetnewsApp**, `SelectTopicButton.kt` only have `@Preview()` tags. When in any file we have `@Preview()` it will automatically show preview in the right side.

In **show decoration** mode you can get the preview of the item with the mobile image, how does it look on the screen.

To get a live preview we need to add `@Preview` tag before `@Composable` tag and the fun must have something to render.

[image]
[image]

I had tried adding `@Preview()` and `@Preview("MyScreen preview")` in JetnewsApp.kt and it shows the preview.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but as I mentioned in my question I already added @Preview annotation and even then it didn't work. I wokred when I build and re open.

Comment: There is a delay when we add preview tag in the file. I think as this is the canary version, the official release will have some solution for this or may be the delay will get short.

Answer (score 2):

btw currently `@Preview` just work for `@Composable` function **without** params. so please check again your composable function

Comment: It will also work for parameters with default value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the preview wouldn't show. The problem was that I had a call to `setContent` in the function also. Removing this and rebuilding rendered the preview as expected.

So

```
    @Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320)
    @Composable
    fun PreviewMainScreen() {
        setContent {
            Greeting()
        }
    }
```

would fail and

```
    @Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 320)
    @Composable
    fun PreviewMainScreen() {
        Greeting()
    }
```

worked as expected.

Surprisingly, and this is the bit I don't understand, once the preview had rendered correctly, I could add the `setContent` again and it would update and still show.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the answers in the previous post helped. However, I want to add a simple feature that will assist while minor modifications are made to the Jetpack compose code, preventing the need to frequently launch your app in order to view the altered layout.

Steps

1. Live edit of literals should be ON. It will be placed to the left side of Code|Split|Design.
2. Start interactive mode. It will be placed to the page of function preview. below Code|Split|Design.